# Perform union and count from two tables

Tags: sql-server, count

I have two tables:

Table A '**Real Orders**':

- Contract,
- Order ID,
- YYYYMM

Table B '**Uploads**':

- Contract,
- Order ID,
- YYYYMM

I want to make a query with the following structure:

*Contract, YYYYMM, Nb of Real Orders, Nb of Uploads*

How can I accomplish that knowing that some contracts from Table A don't appear in Table B and vice-versa? I am use SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried splitting the code into two sub queries, let me know if this works..

```
select coalesce(a.contract,b.contract) as contract,  
       coalesce(a.YYYYMM,b.YYYYMM) as YYYYMM,
       no_real_orders,
       no_uploads 
from 
(
select contract,YYYYMM, count (order_id) as no_real_orders,
from Table_a 
group by contract, YYYYMM
) as a
full join
(
select contract,YYYYMM, count (order_id) as no_uploads,
from Table_b
group by contract, YYYYMM 
) as b
on a.contract = b.contract
and a.YYYYMM = b.YYYYMM
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works

```
select coalesce( a.contract,b.contract) as contract,  
       coalesce(a.YYYYMM,b.YYYYMM) as YYYYMM,
       count (a.order_id) as no_real_orders,
       count (b.order_id) as no_uploads 
from Table_a as a
full join Table_b as b
on a.contract = b.contract
   and a.YYYYMM = b.YYYYMM
group by coalesce(a.contract,b.contract), coalesce(a.YYYYMM,b.YYYYMM)
```

Comment: Hi Tarun, Unfortunately, I get the same count for both columns. Here is an excerpt from the output: Contract YYYYMM Nb Real Orders Nb Uploads
Contract_x 201701 17 17
Contract_x 201612 72 72
Contract_y 201702 196 196
Contract_y 201612 345 345
Contract_y 201701 264 264
 The code is:

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I get the same count for both columns. Here is an excerpt from the output:

```
Contract YYYYMM Nb Real Orders Nb Uploads
Contract_x  201701  17  17
Contract_x  201612  72  72
Contract_y  201702  196 196
Contract_y  201612  345 345
Contract_y  201701  264 264
```

The code is:

```
select coalesce(a.Contract_Code,b.Contract_Code) as Contract,
coalesce(a.OIA_Creation_Date_YYYYMM,b.Ordear_Creation_YYYYMM) as
YearMonth, count(a.OIA_Order_Number) as Nb_Real_Orders,
count(b.Order_Number) as Nb_Uploads from Raw_Data_A as a full join
Raw_Data_B as b on a.Contract_Code=b.Contract_Code and
a.OIA_Creation_Date_YYYYMM=b.Ordear_Creation_YYYYMM group by
 coalesce(a.Contract_Code,b.Contract_Code),coalesce(a.OIA_Creation_Date_YYYYMM,b.Ordear_Creation_YYYYMM)
```